# Create a shortcode displaying simple products names list in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

Does anyone have a function to create a shortcode to list all products names? Don't need images, links, descriptions, sorting — just a simple template like.

```
<ul>
<li>ProductName1</li>
<li>ProductName2</li>
...
<li>ProductNameN</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note: I already found a good function which creates a full list – http://www.gallagherwebsitedesign.com/blog/woocommerce-shortcode-to-display-all-products/. But it returns all links, images etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this simple shortcode that will output a product list based on a `WP_Query`:

```
function get_custom_product_list() {

    // The WP_Query
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'title',
    ) );

    $output = '<ul>';

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $output .= '<li>' . $query->post->post_title . '</li>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output.'</ul>'; 
} 
add_shortcode( 'product_list', 'get_custom_product_list' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Usage:** `[product_list]`